# Query mysql table using ruby by reading filter data from file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I have to run a `query` against a `table (tableA)` and fetch 10 million or so `id's (varchar)` and then use those id's in the `WHERE` clause of a different `table (tableB)` on a different server. I am doing this using ruby.

Here is what I currently have:

I fetch required id's from table1 using the below code and place it in a txt file:

```
system("#{queryToExecute} -e \"#{queryFromSource} \"> #{csvfilename}.txt")
```

`queryToExecute` is a straight forward `select` statement on table1:

Sample rows from the txt file

```
7fa6530f-309e-435f-a64b-099514bccfb3
b408db72-2929-4121-a6fb-5589520914fb
942eb682-2ce0-4462-b773-144e9255e37c
ed3adc78-7fa3-423c-932b-b97a46b2fa07
```

I then do some cleanup on the text file with results using:

```
system("sed '1d' #{csvfilename}.txt > #{csvfilename}_temp.txt;mv #{csvfilename}_temp.txt #{csvfilename}.txt")

    system("paste -d',' -s #{csvfilename}.txt > #{csvfilename}_temp.txt;mv #{csvfilename}_temp.txt #{csvfilename}.txt")

    filedata = File.read(csvfilename+".txt")

    filedata =   filedata.gsub!(",","','") 
    filedata =   filedata.gsub!("\n","") 
    filedata = "'" + filedata +   "'"
@ids = filedata
```

After cleanup, this is what I have in @ids:

```
'7fa6530f-309e-435f-a64b-099514bccfb3','b408db72-2929-4121-a6fb-5589520914fb','942eb682-2ce0-4462-b773-144e9255e37c','ed3adc78-7fa3-423c-932b-b97a46b2fa07'
```

Now I substitute `@ids` in my new query and execute same as above.
My final query looks something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table2 WHERE ids IN #{@ids}
```

The problem I am facing is when there are millions of id's to search, It does not return complete result set. However, if I limit my `id's` from table1 I get required results..

Since the query is huge I am not able to print and validate.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you post how that csv file looks like and how you'd like to query the table based on this file's content?

Comment: @Surya: Included required info above

Comment: 10 million IDs is a lot - do you really need to query the database with every single one of them?

Comment: sadly yes.. I need to do this for all of them.

Comment: You could try splitting up the `@ids` array and run the query multiple times.
This can add some overhead but can get the job done
You can try  using http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice to split the array